# How-to find out what causes a didHideZoomSlider error on IOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8, crashlytics

The following error keeps coming up in my app's crashlytics logs

on IOS 8:

```
libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 5 didHideZoomSlider:

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000e
```

I have no clue where to start?
Anybody an idea on what I should be looking for?

The whole stacktrace :

```
 0
libobjc.A.dylib     
objc_msgSend + 5 
didHideZoomSlider:
1 Foundation    
__NSFireDelayedPerform + 468
2
CoreFoundation  
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
3
CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 650
4
CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopRun + 1418
5
CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
6
    CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
7
GraphicsServices    
GSEventRunModal + 136
8
UIKit   
UIApplicationMain + 1440
9
main.m line 8
main
```

Does the error msg mean that something is going wrong with an ImagePickerCameraView ?

I also sometimes get

```
 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
 EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xeec1ff5e
 0 libobjc.A.dylib  objc_msgSend + 21 didHideZoomSlider:
```

If ImagePicker is the troublemaker here is an code excerpt :

```
- (IBAction)onTakePictureToolbarButtonPushed:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:
        [UIImagePickerController  isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]
            ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
            : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary
    ];

    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}



- (void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage* rawImage = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(rawImage, 0.3);
[imageData writeToFile: @"img.jpg" atomically: YES];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:nil];
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: You should paste your code :)

Comment: The codebase is quite large and I have no clue what is causing the error?

Comment: Since didHideZoomSlider: is a method from CAMCameraView class (It's a private one), you should analyze the portion of the code that use the Camera.

Comment: I added the code but it really looks innocent to me ....

Comment: We cannot help you this way.

Comment: yes I know. But you did help me with pointing me  to the CAMCameraView. It is just ... no matter what I do I can't reproduce the crash. but anyway thank you for commenting

Comment: To replicate: When you zoom in there is a slider bar that appears, which animates out after about 3 seconds. I believe the 'didHideZoomSlider' is called once this completes. You need to zoom, then either take a picture or cancel so that the view is dismissed. For it to crash, the view must be dismissed after the slider starts to fade but before it finishes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've been able to replicate this issue in my code. This seems to be a bug in Apple's code and is a timing issue.

I haven't replicated it by clicking to actually take a photo, but I can replicate it when I hit cancel. You can try doing this in your code and seeing if it works for you. Open up the camera to take a photo and then pinch to zoom. You'll get a little zoom slider show up on the screen. After about 4-5 second that zoom slide fades away. This is where timing comes in. If you click cancel *just* as it starts to fade you can get it to crash.

My assumption is that Apple has an animation block in which it fades the zoom slider. In the completion of that animation it calls `didHideZoomSlider:` without checking it's reference to the image picker.

I think it is easier to replicate on my cancel code because it was very simple:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My assumption is that since this executes so fast it is able to dismiss it in the middle of that animation. Therefore my solution is to actually delay my dismissal of the view by a small amount of time.

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    __weak typeof(self) wSelf = self;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [wSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

I don't think this "fixes" the issue, but reduces it such that I'm unable to replicate it anymore. This should be filed as a bug with Apple (which I'll do next).

Update: Sent to Apple.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can confirm I can reproduce the error (although I need 10 tries). On the subject is there a place where I can look up all IOS bug reports and follow their status. thank you so much again!!

Comment: Yeah, it took me a few times also. :) It looks like you can't look up someone else's bug report (I didn't know this either). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports

Comment: Wouldn't this fix just shift the timing bug without actually removing it?

Comment: @RonLugge that is correct. As mentioned, it doesn't actually fix the bug. See adamup's answer below. That seems to be a better "fix" to it.

Comment: @RyanJM unfortunately, it only fixes it for cancel -- not for the also associated crash when actually *taking* the photo.

Comment: Do you know (i.e. did your bug report get updated) if this has been fixed in iOS9?

Comment: I have no workarounds in place (yet), and I am seeing crash reports for both iOS 8 and iOS 9.

Answer (score 13):

I didn't have much luck with adding the delay.  Crashes still occurred in my case (iOS 8 and 9.0.1).

There's an [OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/18762927) that suggests removing the delegate of the `CAMZoomSlider` likely responsible for the crash, and this worked well for me.

*User beware, though, as this manipulates a private class and may result in an App Store submission rejection...*

To fix issue with delegate, subclass `UIImagePickerController` and add the following:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self clearZoomSliderDelegateForClass:[self sliderClass] subviews:self.view.subviews];
}

- (void)clearZoomSliderDelegateForClass:(Class)sliderClass subviews:(NSArray *)subviews {
    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:sliderClass] && [subview respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]) {
            [subview performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:nil];
            return;
        }
        else {
            [self clearZoomSliderDelegateForClass:sliderClass subviews:subview.subviews];
        }
    }
}

- (Class)sliderClass {
    for (NSString* prefix in @[@"CAM", @"CMK"]) {
        Class zoomClass = NSClassFromString([prefix stringByAppendingString:@"ZoomSlider"]);
        if (zoomClass != Nil) {
            return zoomClass;
        }
    }
    return Nil;
}
```

In iOS 9 SDK private CameraKit framework prefix changed from `CAM` to `CMK` (just check slider with visual debugger), so previous workaround had to be updated.

This crash may also look like this in logs:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x3591fae6 objc_msgSend + 6
1   Foundation                           0x24d28e59 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 466
...
```

Comment: Anyone using this in a production app?

Comment: I've been using it production for several months - no issues, to date.  Didn't get rejected during App Store review.

Comment: Thanks so much - this helped me to avoid the crash... BTW I am still on 8.3.

Comment: Bug fixed on iOS 9? Is safe to run this work-around on iOS 9?

Comment: I haven't checked to see if it's fixed on iOS 9, but I have it in production on iOS 9 without any problems, so far.

Comment: I noticed that original "objc_msgSend" crashes no longer occur, but received two crash reports such as:
-[UITextView didHideZoomSlider:]: unrecognized selector sent
-[__NSCFType didHideZoomSlider:]: unrecognized selector sent

Comment: It's certainly possible the issue has been fixed in iOS 9, then.  I haven't seen this crash report yet but will report back if I do.

Comment: I have no workarounds in place (yet), and I am seeing crash reports for both iOS 8 and iOS 9.

Comment: @PascalBourque - are you using the updated edit for iOS 9?  An astute editor added in support for the new framework prefix for CameraKit, and it's passing my tests.

Comment: @adamup I just wanted to confirm that the crash had not been fixed by Apple in iOS 9: my unpatched app is still reporting crashes in iOS 9. I will indeed implement the updated workaround.

Comment: @PascalBourque - thanks for the update! greatly appreciated.

Comment: @adamup This saved me a lot of time (after taking a lot of time to diagnose the issue - we are using Cordova). We can confirm it exists in 9 - I've added the code and forked the Cordova Camera Repo (github.com/LiamBateman/cordova-plugin-camera) - it wont get merged back but it may help someone out - thanks for code.

Comment: @LiamB Glad it helped!  Thanks for the feedback re: iOS9.  I haven't seen a single crash since I've added the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered, but another potential solution here would be to retain the image picker controller instance inside the view controller to avoid it being deallocated prior to apple's callback firing.

Comment: Thanks @shawnwall. I've actually got my UIImagePickerController retained and I'm still getting the crash.