# iOS 8 UIImagePickerController crashing on Zoom

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8.1

I am using a regular `UIImagePickerController` to capture photo using the device camera. Following is the code I am using to create the UIImagePickerController,

```
self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
```

and following is the code that I am using to display the UIImagePickerController

```
[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now, when the UIImagePickerController is presented, if I zoom to capture and come back to my presenting view controller, the app crashes irregularly with BAD_ACCESS. After editing the scheme and some debugging, I see the following error,

> -[PLImagePickerCameraView didHideZoomSlider:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x140109400

It seems that the zoom slider delegate is called on an unallocated instance. Anyone else observed this behaviour? I am using working on iOS 8.1 and testing it on iPhone 5S. The search for PLImagePickerCameraView doesn't yield much. Any insights would be really helpful before I decide to go with custom Picker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to find out what causes a didHideZoomSlider error on IOS 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844432/how-to-find-out-what-causes-a-didhidezoomslider-error-on-ios-8)

Comment: @Priyank - How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Adding delay is the only feasible solution for now it seems. Don't want to develop my custom camera functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the `UIImagePickerController` zoom crash, as well.  Adding a delay fixed most, but not all, of the crashes.

The root cause is the controller attempting to callback to a delegate after the delegate has been deallocated.  I ended up implementing a subclassed `UIImagePickerController` to remove the delegate of the slider view.

You can find some sample code I posted on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29959695/1114876).