# UIImagePickerController crash on canceling with zoom present on iOS 8.x only

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In our app we show the Camera modally on top of another UIViewController. On iOS 8.x only, about 1/10 of the time if you zoom you wind up with a crash:

PLImagePickerCameraView didHideZoomSlider:]: message sent to deallocated instance

There is an existing SO post which has a supposed workaround - [How-to find out what causes a didHideZoomSlider error on IOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844432/how-to-find-out-what-causes-a-didhidezoomslider-error-on-ios-8) - but every variation I have tried fails to solve the crash. The suggestion involves putting a delay before `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` . No matter what delay I try I can still reproduce the crash.

It only occurs (1) if you zoom the camera view (2) either choose Cancel or take a photo and exit the camera, all shortly before the zoom indication animation fades away. It appears to be a problem in iOS 8.x which Apple hasn't fixed. It crashes in Apple's code with no involvement in anything we have.

I do see "Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates." but this seems to be unrelated and is also referring to code inside the UIImagePickerController not anything we are doing.

I am about to deal with Apple DTS to see if we can find some way to avoid this or what in the environment might be causing this to happen. I thought to ask here in case anyone has another idea.

This crash did not occur under iOS 7.X. Happens on any model iPhone or iPad.

Comment: `message sent to deallocated instance`. Have you tried keeping a strong reference to the image picker from the presenting view controller?

Comment: Yes, the underlying UIViewController holds the picker in strong ref.

Comment: @ahwulf - How did you resolve this issue? Are making image picker as a weak reference? Even I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Don't forget to add the delay to the dismissal in both `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:` and `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Apple is "it's a bug, file it in Radar" which of course says nothing about when it will be fixed. There is no workaround other than to tell users to wait a little until the slider fades (which our support people tell the users). There is nothing you can do other than implement your own camera and zoom support and do it yourself correctly.

Perhaps Apple will fix it in 8.2.

Comment: Nope, still crashes in 8.2. Perhaps 8.3.

Comment: Still crashing in 8.3 unfortunately.

Comment: Still crashing in 9.2