# Access to CAMZoomSlider instance to clear it's delegate

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I am presently using UIImagePicker and my app crashes on iOS 8 with the following workflow:
Start the camera, zoom it which shows the zoom slider below and then take a picture. Select Use Photo and app crashes.

After looking more into the crash "didHideZoomSlider" message is sent to the deallocated instance of image picker view.

Here is my code:

```
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [myController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:animated completion:nil];
```

I tried a couple of things. My controller holds a strong reference to the image picker, I tried making it a weak reference and the app still crashes. Also I need a strong reference so I actually cannot make it weak.

Although this looks like an Apple bug and someone has already logged it (http://openradar.appspot.com/18762927) I wanted to try the workaround they are using. However I am not able to get to "CAMZoomSlider" through UIImagePicker's instance.

Does anyone know how to get to CAMZoomSlider?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to clear the CAZoomSlider delegate by doing the following in a subclassed UIImagePickerController class. And sure enough, it seems to have resolved the crash.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self clearZoomSliderDelegate:self.view.subviews];
}

- (void)clearZoomSliderDelegate:(NSArray*)subviews
{
    for (UIView *subview in subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"CAMZoomSlider")])
        {
            if ([subview respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]) {
                [subview performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:nil];
            }

            return;
        }
        else if (subview.subviews != nil) {
            [self clearZoomSliderDelegate:subview.subviews];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Zackpep, I am bit afraid of using this code, will it reject the app in the app store if I use this code.

Comment: I had concerns about that too but my app has not been rejected because of this.

Comment: FYI, the name of the private class changed in iOS 9 to CMKZoomSlider, so your solution will need to be modified to check for both. Take a look at the similar solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29959695/406797